# DRF Serializers. Different fields on serialize and deserialize methods

Tags: serialization, django-rest-framework, deserialization

What is the best approach to have the same field name in Serializer but different behaviour on serializing and deserializing data? (I want to put only group_id on input and get full related info on the output)

So I want my schema looks like this when I input my data

```
{
  "group": 1,
  "other_fields": []
  ...
}
```

But got this (This is the way i want data looks like on the output only)

```
{
  "group": {
    "name": "string",
    "description": "string",
    "image": "string",
    "is_public": true
  },
  "other_fields": []
  ...
}
```

My serializer right now

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    group = GroupSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = "__all__"
```

---

**Edit:** Added group serializer and my Group model. Nothing special

```
class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = "id", "owner", "name", "description", "image", "is_public"
        read_only_fields = "owner",
```

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    owner = models.ForeignKey("user.User", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=func)
    is_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Comment: can you update your question and add `GroupSerializer()`?

Comment: @AD I added some additional information

Comment: Input data you mean it's for create and output it's result of creation, right? If yes, just do it in separated serializer, one for create another to retrieve data

Comment: @BaktiyarBekbergen yes, that is the way I am doing it right now, but looking for unifying solutions

Comment: @Ayudesee there is not unifying solutions, you can not say to your serializer make 2 difference thing

Answer (score 0):

In your `TaskSerializer` class you are serializing `group` with `GroupSerializer()`, which serializes the relation as an object with the fields you specified in it's implementation.

You instead want to serialize a single field, for that you could use `SlugRelatedField(slug_field='id')` which serializes the relation as a single field from `group`.

Because your Group model doesn't have a primary key field, Django generates an automatic `AutoField(primary_key=True)` id field, thus you can use `PrimaryKeyRlatedField()`.

Try:

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    group = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField()

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = "__all__"
```

For more examples, I suggest reading [this tip from testdriven.io](https://testdriven.io/tips/b8b6b33e-6b62-4168-9071-e50050b4b316/).